# Font encodings T1 and T5 coexist?

Tags: fonts

I have a file that needs characters from both font encodings T1 and T5 (it has both Vietnamese and Icelandic characters).  How do I turn them both on?  Do I need to turn them on one at a time?  The file is 19102 lines.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could set the Icelandic text with `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont` and the Vietnamese text with `\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont` However normally at a language switch you would need other changes such as for hyphenation so a language switch command from babel or similar package can usually be set up to do whatever settings are needed for each language.

Comment: I'm printing a genealogy file with 19000 entries.  Do I need \fontencoding{Tx}\selectfont before each one?  The font needed to print each individual's name isn't in the database from which the report is extracted.  Do I really need to insert it manually before each record?

Comment: @VanSnyder you only need `\selectfont` where you change fonts, (actually you should almost never need that explictly in a document) You haven't really given any information to allow anyone to give more explicit help. Presumably? you know from somewhere whether it is an Icelandic or Vietnamese name you are printing?

Comment: I know from looking at the names whether they're Vietnamese or Icelandic or from somewhere else.  There's nothing in the database from which the file was generated.  Icelandic characters are (mostly) represented by national-choice characters (ASCII 161-266) in 8859-1.  Vietnamese characters are represented using VIQR.  I have a post processor that scans for these things and replaces them with commands from T1 or T5, such as \dh{} (for ð) or \ohorn (for the Vietnamese "o" with a mark that looks like a little question mark).  I don't think any names have characters from both fonts.

Comment: There are more than 19000 lines in the file, so it's not practical to edit it manually.  Since this is a genealogy file, there will be many font changes, not ubiquitous, but also not "almost never."

Comment: @VanSnyder you may prefer to use xelatex or lualatex in which you could typeset both languages with the same font, using unicode encodings rather than legacy 8bit encodings such as T1 or T5. For pdflatex you _could_ define each character to come from a specific font,  but if you typeset the start of a word in T1 as ascii letters thaen switch fonts to T5 when you find a Vietnamese character then you will lose any possibility of inter-letter kerns or ligaures, and you woruld disable hyphenation.